# Paperclip loading images from assets/images directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, paperclip

how can I call out image using paperclip gem if the image is stored in asset/images/Garden3.jpeg ? I added the record myself using rails console and the following is the value in the DB :

```
#<Product id: 1, product_code: "FB_60", product_description: "Fruits: Apple,Orange,Banana Flowers: Zebra, Chrysa...", price: #<BigDecimal:7f9ec73ec430,'0.6E2',9(18)>, product_image_file_name: "Garden3.jpeg", product_image_content_type: "jpeg", product_image_file_size: nil, product_image_updated_at: nil, category_id: 1>
```

I have an image in the directory asset/images/Garden3.jpeg. Product model will load the images and display the image, price & details . In my Product model i have :

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category

  has_attached_file :product_image, styles: { small: "64x64", med: "100x100", large: "200x200" },
    :url => "/system/products/product_images/000/000/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
    :path => ":rails_root/app/assets/images/:basename:extension"

end
```

I've also permitted the param name **:product_image** in the controller. However, when i run the app, there isn't any image shown except the image icon:

[image]

May i know how can i deal with this problem ? Thanks and appreciate it if I can get some explaination on it to improve.

Answer (score 0):

Even i had faced similar problem when i deployed my rails app to Heroku.
After lot of trying, thing that worked for me was i tried remove extension of filename. In your case:

```
Save data row as `#<Product id: 1, product_code: "FB_60", product_description: "Fruits: Apple,Orange,Banana Flowers: Zebra, Chrysa...", price: #<BigDecimal:7f9ec73ec430,'0.6E2',9(18)>, product_image_file_name: "Garden3", product_image_content_type: "jpeg", product_image_file_size: nil, product_image_updated_at: nil, category_id: 1>`
```

Hope it works for you or else try play with extension of filename.

`